# No symbolic links in Loki?

Tags: folder

I do not know how to create symbolic links in elementary OS Loki, and my attempts have resulted in errors. (I've tried drag drop and the context menu to no avail).

I notice that Drag & drop defaults to Copy instead of giving the menu option. I also tried Thunar's "Send To" which appears to crash the system. I don't feel comfortable using the terminal, so I wish to do this using the GUI if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Files** application built-in to EOS it's actually really easy:

- Drag and drop the file / folder on top of itself (you will see a `?` instead of the usual drag icon)
- A context menu will show with `link here`
- Then a symlink will be created in the same folder
- Now drag that wherever you like!

This definitely works in Loki, I've just done it.

The parent Distro, Ubuntu seems to also support this with middle click. Do you have a three button mouse? - I'm using a touchpad so I can't test:

> GUI   You can easily create a symbolic link to a folder or file by
>   middle clicking on the folder with the mouse and dragging it to its
>   new location, while holding the middle mouse button.

http://ubuntuhak.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/symbolic-links-in-ubuntu.html

Otherwise you'll need to use the command line probably.

Answer (score 1):

In the Files application, open two folders in different windows, for example, one in ~/Downloads and the other in ~/Documents.

Select your file, now drag it to the other window while keeping the RIGHT button down. When you release the button, a small menu pops up letting you choose whether to move, copy or link the file

[image]

You do have to have write priviliges to the folder you are dropping the file to. making links in /usr/bin, for example is best left to the command-line.